# What is the $n$th Cyclotomic Polynomial for a given $n$

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Are there any formula to compute the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial for a given $n$? I know how to compute it for small $n$, but for large $n$, I need a general formula..

Comment: You can use that the product of the d-th cyclotomic polynomials, where d is a divisor of n is equal to $x^n -1$, and you should get your answer without too much trouble if $n$ is somewhat reasonable. If it is very large, use sage.

Comment: Thanks.. I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general formula:
$$
\Phi_{n}(x)=\prod _{d\mid n}(x^{d}-1)^{\mu \left({\frac {n}{d}}\right)}
$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. It follows by using Möbius inversion on
$$
x^{n}-1=\prod _{d\mid n}\Phi_{d}(x)
$$
This also gives a recursive formula for $\Phi _n$:
$$
\Phi_n(x) = \frac{x^{n}-1}{\prod _{d\mid n, d\ne n}\Phi_{d}(x)}
$$
Note that both formulas express $\Phi_n$ as a rational function which simplifies to a polynomial.

It is unlikely that there is a general formula for the coefficients of $\Phi _n$ in monomial form.

Comment: All this and more is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159487/proving-the-möbius-formula-for-cyclotomic-polynomials